# Do we write our own method in reducer class

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Hi i'm creating a Hash map in the reducer phase.. Now i want to use the final hashmap in other function. my question is do we write our own methods in our reduce class(in this code it is ColocationReducer) and **where** do we call that method. reducer method is called by default.. if we write our own method **how can we call** that method.

And do we write another class in mapreduce program along with mapper, reducer classes.. we set the job to the mapper and reducer classes.

```
         job.setMapperClass(ColocationMapper.class);
         job.setReducerClass(ColocationReducer.class);
```

If i write one more class contains a method Display(), which displays the key values of hash map which we created in reducer class. How can we call this method and where we include the code for calling this Display().

```
 public static class ColocationReducer extends Reducer <Text, Text, Text, Text>

 { 

          Map<String, List<String>> hash = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
         public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            List<String> queries = new ArrayList<String>(); 
            String result=" ";
                for (Text val : values) {
                queries.add(val.toString());
                }

            for (String str : queries){
                result=result.concat(str);
                result=result.concat(" ");  
            }
            hash.put(key.toString(), queries);
                context.write(key,new Text(result));

            }
    }
```

Comment: I am confused with "i want to use the final hashmap in other function"  what is the purpose of that function? seems you need another mapreduce procedure

Comment: As i have created hashmap in reducer class,  I want to write a function which displays that hash map.